# How to detect a "drag" within an input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have an input field that looks like this:

```
<input id="test" value="abdefg" />
```

I would like a jQuery event that detects if I *drag* a text around within the input field. With *drag* I mean that you first select *ab* and drag that selection so it ends up after the *g*.

Is it possible to detect stuff like this?

Comment: Looks like a two step process: 1. Detect select of text. 2. Detect the drag start/end events. Complicated by keyboard selection, and possible drag options (just mouse, or allow keyboard combo with arrow keys). good question though +1 on that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any specific event that is triggered when text is dragged. But it should be possible to just save the value of the field on mousedown and then compare it to the new value of the field when the mouseup event is triggered. If the value has changed, something was dragged.

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Hm... I'll try to write up an JSFiddle example to see if it works.

Comment: I'm also just fiddling around a bit and can't get it to work. Seems like the mouseup-event isn't event triggered when dragging text.

Comment: However, It you combine that idea with the input-element that was proposed in other answers, it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/86K89/ (tested in latest Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: Ok, one final update because my last fiddle also fired when typing while the mouse-button was pressed: http://jsfiddle.net/ghb83/

Comment: @Simon, nice! Looks like it works, I'm still doing some testing :D

Answer (score 3):

There is no event specifically for that purpose, but this action would be caught by the `oninput` event.

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qGzav/1**

Note that the `oninput` isn't supported by IE8 and lower, but it can be emulated using the `onpropertychange` event.  I have a plugin that normalizes this event for all the major browsers - http://whattheheadsaid.com/projects/input-special-event.

Comment: @Tim: haha :-) it's nice to see others preaching the `oninput` event for a change!

Comment: Doesn't really do something for me.

Comment: @Kees: what do you mean by "Doesn't really do something for me"?  Which browser did you use to test it.  When you drag the text in the example, it should update the element after it with a copy of the new value of the text field.  Or did you mean it doesn't get your juices going, because I know of this place nearby where they can sort you out with that kind of thing... ahem!

Comment: I'm using IE and when I drag something, nothing gets updated. I'm not so interested in getting juices going ;-).

Comment: @Kees: I didn't include the compatibility code for IE - I've updated the example now.  I'd recommend using the plugin I linked to though, so that the input change only fires one event handler and bubbling works the same way.